# "kubeadm upgrade apply v1.18.0-00" does not seem to upgrade the master node

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade, kubectl, kubeadm

I'm quite confused here on this `kubeadm upgrade`.

As you can see from my screenclips below, my *serverVersion* is stuck at v1.17.2 when displaying `kubectl version -o json` from my Mac.

When I'm on my MASTER node, I issued the `kubeadm upgrade plan` and the system displays the `kubeadm upgrade apply v1.18.0` to upgrade.

But, after the upgrade, my CURRENT version is still showing v1.17.2.

You can see from the 3rd screenclip with `kubectl get nodes -o wide` that the nodes are all showing v1.18.0.

But, `kubectl version -o json`, still shows the serverVersion at v1.17.2.

Also, my k9s continues to show my **K8s Rev: v1.17.2**

Adding to the question.

Why on the MASTER node, when entering kubectl version would the Client & Server versions be DIFFERENT?  Which is shown in the 2nd to last screen clip below.

Isn't the kubectl on the MASTER node both the CLIENT & SERVER? I mean if I am ssh'd into the MASTER node, and I use kubectl, am I not issuing a CLIENT request ON the SERVER itself? So, how can the CLIENT & SERVER versions be different?

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
[image: sc1]
[image: sc2]
[image: sc3]
[image: sc4]
[image: sc5]
[image: sc6]

Comment: do you have multiple contexts, clusters configured in the kubeconfig file referred by kubectl?

Comment: I do not have multiple contexts. I am just using the kubernetes-admin@kubernetes.

Comment: Have you upgraded `kubelet` and other host-running applications?

Comment: Yes...I did upgrade the `kubelet` on all nodes (MASTER & WORKER).  I added my screen clip showing this in the thread.

Comment: Please check manifest folder `/etc/kubernetes/manifest` for any backup files foe API server.  (e.g. kube-apiserver.yaml.xxxx). Move these files somewhere else and restart `kubelet`.

Comment: Many thanks!  I had edited these manifest files with emacs, and emacs created it's normal ~ backups for each of the files.  I deleted these backups, and, voilà, the Client and Server versions MATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `emacs` had created its normal backup files in the */etc/kubernetes/manifests* files, and this was creating the problem. I'm not sure WHY `kubectl` had an issue with these backup files, but after I removed these backups from the directory, you can see my `kubectl version` for the *Client* & *Server* versions match.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic2]

Thanks Nick!

Comment: Had a similiar issue. I had a copy of kube-apiserver.yaml in this directory ...

Answer (score 1):

My comment:

> Please check manifest folder /etc/kubernetes/manifest for any backup files foe API server. (e.g. kube-apiserver.yaml.xxxx). Move these files somewhere else and restart kubelet.

was inspired by pretty good discussion on that issue at ["Kubernetes/issues"](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1617) section on Github.

> Since kubelet uses every file in this folder one of the older ones must have been the winner when starting the pod.

Additionally there is an pull request  (PR)
 in this [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1694). The outcome is that on Jan 17th, 2020 the PR was **merged** to master from neolit123:1.18-kubeadm-ugprade-rollback.

That is why you shouldn't face that very issue next time you'll be updating k8s *from* 1.18.x :-)

Hope that helps.